# Testing Python AWS Lambda boto3 initialization

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, mocking, boto3, python-unittest

For lambda, it's [best practice](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/best-practices.html) to initialise dependencies outside the handler.

I am creating a simple python function that works like the blueprints:

```
import boto3


s3 = boto3.client('ssm')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # some code here
```

And the test

```
from lambda_function import handler # Option 1
import lambda_function              # Option 2

class TestHandler(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('lambda_function.handler.boto3.client')
    def test(self, boto3_mock):
        # ...
```

I can't seem to properly setup a mock so that the `boto.client` call doesn't error out with `You must specify a region.`

On `Option 1` it errors out during import call, and on `Option 2` it does so during the `patch` setup

I can't use a `~/.aws/config` because it will be used on a CI that can't have that. I also don't wan't to change the `boto.client` call to include a default region.

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue with boto3 s3 client in my client class and moto in my pytest. I resolved it by wrapping boto3 client into a singleton:

This is my client code hello_world/app.py

```
class Singleton(type):
_instances = {}
def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    if cls not in cls._instances:
        cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    return cls._instances[cls]

class S3BotoClient(metaclass=Singleton):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        print(f"creating s3 cient with args {args}")
        self.client = boto3.client("s3", *args)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3 = S3BotoClient().client
    s3.list_buckets()
```

And this is a unit test:

```
from moto import mock_s3
from hello_world import app

@pytest.fixture()
def apigw_event():
    # return some sample event here

@mock_s3
def test_lambda_handler(apigw_event):
    ret = app.lambda_handler(apigw_event, "")
    ret = app.lambda_handler(apigw_event, "")
    # do assertions here
```

So S3 client is instantiated only once and after moto virtual env is initialized

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not sure what the issue is with the above code, I'd advise you to use the moto library when you are trying to mock AWS services in Python (https://github.com/spulec/moto):

```
import boto3
from moto import mock_s3
from lambda_function import handler

class TestHandler(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock_s3
    def test(self, boto3_mock):
       # setup your connection to s3 or ssm. Make sure this matches the setup in the lambda file.
       conn = boto3.client('s3')
       conn.create_bucket(Bucket='mybucket') # setup your fake resources
       # call your lambda function
```

In addition - and as a somewhat personal preference - I would advise against putting too much logic in your actual lambda function. Just take the incoming event send it to other functions/classes as much as possible. This should help simplify testing.

If you really want to keep using @patch instead of the moto library, I got the code to work with the following:

```
from mock import patch
from example import lambda_function

class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('example.lambda_function.boto3.client')
    def test_my_model(self, some_mock):
        # further setup of test
        lambda_function.my_handler(None, None)
```

Here, *lambda_function* is the file containing your handler, and it is located in the directory/package *example*. You could also mock boto3 itself with *'example.lambda_function.boto3'* and return a client yourself.

Comment: Thanks @hieron, the logic is not on the actual lambda handler, so testing the code is fine, my problem is in the test setup.
The problem with the above example is that the `boto.client` call in the source code would be executed on line #3 of the example (`from lambda_function import handler`) and give the region error

Comment: Can you try the suggestions I added to my answer?